Connecting two Phantom powers in series
I'm using an audio interface (Behringer UMC404HD) which can deliver a Phantom Power +48V with 4 XLR entries, 3 static mics and I want to add 2 mics for my accordion which also require a Phantom Power supply. I have a solution: I can connect them to the same (9V) battery power supply (JTS PS-500) and connect this box to the last entry of my audio interface.
My question is: would it damage something if I had Phantom Power supply coming from the audio interface & the external battery at the same time?

My guess is that the PS500 might become harmed by 48V phantom power. The newer PS510 is a better bet.

If I put a XLR (from the PS500) to jack (to the audio interface) adapter, wouldn't it also resolve all my problems (since phantom power does not come out of jack entries)?

@LouisLascaud Well spotted. That should work. XLR to TRS, a so called balanced cable,
